# Python face_recognition takes too long to process each frame

Tags: python, face-recognition, opencv

Hey I am using the following code from face_recognition github: [code](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/blob/master/examples/facerec_from_webcam.py)
Everything works out beside that I am getting 2 fps/sec when It detects a face, when it is not, the frame rate is ~30.

I looked up on task manager to see how's my computer doing and The CPU is on ~15% as well as the GPU so it isn't hardware problem. I also tried changing the resolution to 320x240 but It did nothing same problem.

How can I increase the fps?
Edit:
I have only one encoding to process so multi threading will probably not help

Answer (score 1):

There are two processing steps to this program:

1. In the while loop, face_detection searches for faces in the frame, and then encodes them (uses linear algebra to simplify the face data into unique vectors).
2. In the for loop (which only runs once a face is detected), the program runs the encoding from step 1 against all other "known" encodings, returning the best match if it meets the default threshold of certainty.

If you have modified the code at all, increasing the number of "known" faces, it would slow the process down some. Also, I do not know how optimized the threading is. It is possible that some of the program is running on a single thread, which would show lower CPU usage even though the program is maxing what it has efficient access to.

**Troubleshooting steps**: Inside of loop #2 (the for loop), start by commenting out the framing lines (or everything after compare_faces), and see if it speeds up. That way you can narrow in on what is taking the most processing power. If you find that compare_faces **IS** the bottleneck, try decreasing the number of "known" faces. If that drastically increases fps, it is likely you are limited by number of cores/threading.

---

The example code you are using is a less optimized version. [Here](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/blob/master/examples/facerec_from_webcam_faster.py) is a slightly faster version. Tweaks include:

1. Process each video frame at 1/4 resolution (though still display it at full resolution)
2. Only detect faces in every other frame of video.

Basically by decreasing the amount of processing it will speed up the processing rate.

Comment: Thank you for the info, but unfortunately it did not solve the problem, I tried using the optimized version and commenting what you said and I get the same result, I bet the problem is the cores usage I am using only one.

Comment: Do you only load the 2 faces "obama" and "biden" as in the example code? If it is only comparing against 2 faces, i don't think multi-threading will help you. Also did you try the [python profiler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html)?

Comment: Actually I am loading one xD what is the problem hmm

Comment: It is also possible the slowdown is in the encoding stage in the while loop (as this only runs when a face is found)

Comment: My last thought is enabling CUDA (if you have a compatible GPU) and using a CUDA specific version of the opencv library.

Comment: I just installed it so I dont think its that, also tried now to run with all cores working and same result, guess we'l wait for further answers

Comment: Running with more cores is only helpful if the task can be split between threads. If you are only detecting and thus encoding one face, and comparing it to a database of one "known" faces, multi-threading won't speed it up. What CPU are you using? GPU?

Comment: AMD FX 8350 with 8 cores, GTX 970 and 8GB of ram

Comment: I don't know hardware bottlenecks super well, but setup looks fine. the GTX 970 is CUDA compatible if you decide to go that route (should get some performance buffs). Otherwise I guess just wait for a more informed answer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same project on both my Windows PC and Macbook pro with OSX. I found that the FPS on MacBook pro can reach more than 30 FPS while the windows PC can only run at 2 FPS. The CPU on my Windows PC is Ryzen 3900X and my MacBook uses a i9 CPU. From my perspective, the bottleneck is not the CPU itself, the operating system should be the main issues. Try to install a Linux based OS and do it again. I don't know the reason but Linux does have these advantages.